# Multi-threading search of a large solution space

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have to search a large solution space (enumerating all Latin Squares of a specific order) for valid solutions. I'm trying out multi-threading (boost::thread). I split up the solution space in subspaces and investigate a particular subspace within a single thread. This works well, since there are no dependencies between the threads.

But now I want to save all valid solutions in a list. Would it be best to use a single list (shared data) and surround it with a mutex or should I create lists (local data) per thread and join the lists after the threads have finished?

There might be millions of valid solutions for higher orders. So the process would either involve a lot of mutex locks/unlocks or it would involve a large memory footprint per thread.

Thanks, 
Daniel Dekkers

Comment: It's the usual speed-vs-space tradeoff. You have to decide which is most important for you.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many lists you'll get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your explanations, you want local lists that gets concatenated at the end of your algorithm. If every thread is going to find many solutions, using in mutexes will slow down drastically your computation. From what I understand of your context, you should consider memory as pretty cheap nowadays, but it's hard to know for sure without knowing the size of a solution.

There can also be list merge algorithms which are minimal in memory space (ie. by copying small amount of data at a time) which may solve small memory footprint issues.

That being said, there are also hybrid solutions to your problem.
You could, for instance, create a shared container and partition it in order to assign partitions to each thread, either interlaced or in block. This would allow you to remove the per-access mutex but would require a complex mechanism of container growth (since it doesn't seems to be possible to know how many solutions you will have beforehand).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tried both ways, doesn't seem to matter much which way to go. Probably because finding a solution is scattered randomly in time. And writing to the list doesn't take much time.

Comment: This means that the current bottleneck of your problem on your environment (machine currently used) is not related to parallelism synchronization points. This maybe will be the case given an optimized algorithm running on enough cores (ie. virtual NUMA machine). Meanwhile, it means that you shouldn't try to optimize too early your parallel scheme because it's not your current bottleneck.